# How to download large files from SageMaker Studio Lab?

Tags: download, amazon-sagemaker, large-files

In Colab one can move large files to Google Drive and then download them easy to local computer but how does one do it in SageMaker Studio Lab? The Download option doesn't work for large files. Do one need to use a script or special application?

Comment: It's in the SageMaker Studio Labs drive, the free 15G drive, not S3.  Labs use notebook like Colab, both have problem with downloading large files to local pc/drive, but in Colab one can use a link to download large files, but in Sagemaker nothing happens. So how is the way doing it? Have googled the whole internet without finding an answer, maybe because Labs is a new feature, but I think it is important that one can download large trained models easy without special tricks, specially in an user-friendly Lab environment.

Comment: Anyway, I have now done a quick fix to handle this. I though hope that someone from the SageMaker-team can answer this question, as this site is the formal site for Q&A. The original download function should work in SageMaker Studio Lab for large files or write/communicate a simple script for it.

Comment: Can you please tell me the quick fix that you have used, I am also not able to download the file

Comment: As now best is find a free external cloud drive and upload your files to it. E.g. if you are in a Kaggle competition you can install the Kaggle codes, create a private dataset remotely with the api script. Maybe aws have free drives to use? I hope they create an easy script to the Studio Lab drive for downloading the files locally or making a drive GUI that works for download large files. Btw, I have collected other codes that one can use to maximum the Studio Lab experience, I'll find somewhere to post it. Maybe I create an own question here and answer it with the codes and examples.

Comment: Okay I was using kaggle and hoping there was some other way too... As I tried copying the download link as well, it is also taking forever

Comment: Studio Labs is new, so it will surely pop up a solution soon.

Comment: google drive works too for me with the `gdrive` CLI utility: [github link](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a file in your SageMaker Studio Lab project to your local system, you can right click on the file in the file browser UI in the left panel and select "Download".

Comment: No, as I stated "problem with downloading large files to local pc/drive, but in Colab one can use a link to download large files, but in Sagemaker nothing happens". Does downloading e.g. 750Mb file works for you when using the "Download" button? When using say a script uploading to a cloud drive it just takes seconds. I should be easy and informative as Studio Lab is for many new users testing around.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload your file to AWS S3 storage and then download it by clicking the "download" button. I had uploaded a 1.3GB file and download the file successfully.

Comment: Do they have some AWS S3 storage free of charge?

Comment: sorry. i did not check the S3 storage cost. can try the AWS Free Tier.